# Trouble Reproducing CoreData 'could not fulfill a fault' Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I have what I believe is a somewhat typical issue where I delete and update CoreData data on a background thread and while a UITableView is rendering a previously fetch array of CoreData objects, I receive:

```
"NSObjectInaccessibleException CoreData could not fulfill a fault for"
```

I've read a bunch of suggestions how to possibly fix it but before I go blindly adding code, I would like to reproduce the issue first.

For my test case I have three steps.

1. Fetch items from CoreData
2. Create a background thread. In the new thread create long loop (maybe 100 iterations) where the database is erased and reloaded just like in the crash. The background thread creates a new NSManagedObjectContext but shares the PersistantStore with the primary context.
3. Send the main UI thread into an infinite loop (>10,000 iterations) that constantly fetches new items from the primary context and then iterates over the fetched objects. I've also tried this test with simply iterating over the original list of fetched objects without re-fetching.

I would expect this test case to cause the NSObjectInaccessibleException error but everything works perfectly and I am unable to reproduce the crash. Between reviewing my code and not being able to reproduce this error, I feel like I'm doing everything correctly. However, somehow in the wild this crash shows up.

Any idea on how I can recreate this crash?

Answer (score 0):

2. Seems this occurs when Context in background is saved but waiting the main thread to be merged with the main Context or in the process of merging. So try to add more stuff in parallel to the main thread to increase the time between save and merge.
3. In Crashlytics we also get this issue (top 1) and almost always it happens in the private method of [NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:]. (this line is in the middle of the log...). So try to add/remove objects that are associated with the TableView+ NSFetchedResultsController. + more reloadData here.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try to dramatically increase the number of records that are being saved by at least a factor.

Comment: I've added up to 100,000 records to be deleted and saved while I simultaneously reload the UITableVIew that contains the original data. I just can't seem to reproduce this crash yet it still shows up in Crashlytics.